# Making my own video sending network application in C

Tags: c, sockets, video, networking, file-transfer

I had an assignment in networking course, where I implemented a simple client server application that downloads a file (text) from the server to the client. This I did by continuously reading the file on the server side and sending the data by `send` and receiving the data by `recv`calls. Text files work great.

But I want to implement (not part of the assignment) a video sending ability to this app :D (no need of pen drives among friends !). I used the same code as sending file hoping that it will work. If I ran the code on my own machine ( server and client running on my machine) the video was successfully transferred. But when the server and client run on different machines (server on my friend's laptop and client on mine), I get the video file, but a corrupted one ! :(

Server snippet for sending file :

```
void sendFile(FILE * fp, int * arg )
{
    int socket=(int)*arg;

    while(1)
    {
        /* First read file in chunks of 256 bytes */
        char buff[1024]={0};
        if(fp==NULL)
        {
            printf("File open error");
            return;   
        } 

        int nread = fread(buff,1,1024,fp);

        /* If read was success, send data. */
        if(nread > 0)
        {

            if(nread != 1024)
                buff[nread] = 0;
            send(socket, buff, nread,0);
        }
        if (nread < 1024)
        {
            if (ferror(fp))
                printf("Error reading\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Client snippet for receiving file :

```
FILE * fp = fopen(fileName,"wb");
if(fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file");
    return 1;
}

int bytesReceived = 0;
char recvBuff[1024];
while((bytesReceived = recv(socket_client, recvBuff, 1024,0)) > 0)
{ 
    fwrite(recvBuff, 1,bytesReceived,fp);    
    if(bytesReceived < 1024)
        break;
}
fclose(fp);
printf("File successfully downloaded!\n");
```

The video file after download gives the error: `This file is incomplete and cannot be played.`. I really want to make this network application, that I can use in my daily life! Any idea, where the snippets are getting wrong? Any Help Appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: 1) There are *thousands* ready-made and freely available applications that you " can use in daily life", which will be way more convenient  and much more versatile than you command-line program. 2) `recv(socket_client, recvBuff, 1024,0)` - will *not* block if there are less than 1024 bytes received, and it is not guaranteed that any read will give you 1024 bytes right away. But any read like this you treat as an error.

Comment: 1) I said I want to make something that I want to use.
2) Please elaborate / any alternatives ?

Comment: Simple as that, you might receive shorter packages of data and this won't mean there's not more data coming. You'll have to loop until you get `0` (socket shut down) or `-1` (error).

Comment: Okay, I got that. So should be we taking input data, untill we reach the end of file and not less than 1024 bytes ? Will that work ?

Comment: Unlikely. You just send some raw binary data with an unknown format. But you need to be able to detect errors and detect the start and the end of the transmission. I.e. you need a *protocol* defined.

Comment: Keep going till you get 0 bytes received.  Get rid of that '1024' check.

Comment: In the server, close the socket when the file read returns 0 bytes.

Comment: But then how do I detect in the client side when to end the loop. I am thinking of checking the socket connection inside the while loop (or attempt `recv` command and noting down the return value if that is an error), will that suffice ? Can you please give a formal answer, so that I can accept it @MartinJames

Answer (score 0):

Another way - wait for all data of message:

```
while((bytesReceived = recv(socket_client, recvBuff, 1024, MSG_WAITALL)) > 0)
```